# DCF77 antenna preamplifier from available components

Tags: transistors, amplifier, circuit-design, antenna

I plan to build a DCF77 receiver, which includes an active antenna. When I was looking for inspiration to design an antenna preamplifier, I came across a scheme that I liked. Here is the [link](https://www.shotech.de/Datasheet/DCF77/DCF-77-SHO-ANT.PDF). When I wanted to buy the BF256B, I found out that it was no longer in production. The same goes for the BC550B. Therefore, I was wondering if anyone would help me to design a similar circuit diagram but with the difference that transistors can be obtained.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tons of FETs in stock to choose from https://www.digikey.de/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-jfets/288?FV=-8%7C288&quantity=0&ColumnSort=-1000009&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=500

Comment: When you see 3 or 4 digits on the L & C values, you know the Q is high and critical.  Look for ceramic filters, much easier if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a JFET preamp for a WWVB receiver (60 KHz instead of 77.5 KHz):

[image: WWVB front end]

It comes from this youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeYQvsAtdf0

and this tweet:

https://twitter.com/codedweller/status/638824875340132352

I think you could use pretty much any JFET device in place of the NTE457 that has similar specs. You might have to use a SMD package -- e.g. a J309 in a SOT23 package.

The BC550 is just a jellybean NPN transistor. It shares the same datasheet with the BC546, BC547, BC548 and BC549 all of which would probably work.

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc550-d.pdf

Two other jellybean BJT designs for WWVB to consider:

- Hans Summers: http://www.hanssummers.com/images/stories/radio/report.htm
- One by Russell Kincaid published in Nuts and Volts, May 2006:

[image: Kincaid WWVB circuit]

Comment: A pretty, and very well,  hand-drawn schematic! Thank you for this!

Comment: 10.36 nF right !  Filing down ceramic disks with a nail file

Comment: You could also buy a bunch of 10nF caps and bin them. After all, you're going to need a 9.7nF and a 11nF cap, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

The circuit by Pete McNeil (MadSci) looks dodgy and apparently was never fully tested, so I would stay away from it. The DCF-77 receiver circuit in your fist link looks good (apart from the glaring error where the output is shorted to VCC).

Several other JFETs are available that could replace the BF256B, eg. J112, 2N5486. The only issue you may have is getting the correct Drain current. Unfortunately due to unavoidable process variations most JFETs do not have tightly controlled transfer characteristics, so depending on the individual FET you may have to adjust the value of resistor R5 (which produces the Gate-Source bias voltage that controls Drain current).

[image]

The schematic conveniently states that the expected bias voltage is 1.12  V, from which the current through R5 (and Drain current) can be calculated as 1.12 V / 270  Ω = ~4 mA. You should adjust the value of R5 to get close to this current, which should produce the correct Drain voltage. If this is not possible because the FET needs too much bias voltage to keep the current down, reduce the value of R2 to increase Drain voltage and achieve at least 2.5 V between Drain and Source at the higher current draw.